# Partial Sums and the Leibniz Formula for Pi

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I calculate the first few partial sums for the Leibniz Formula? I have to do a total of ten can someone post how to calculate the first few, I'm a bit lost.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \frac{1}{2n+1}$$

Comment: Like, $1$, then $1-\frac13 = \frac23$, then $1-\frac13+\frac15 = \frac{13}{15}$?

Comment: Of course, to calculate $\pi$, you have to multiply the partial sums by $4$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $N$th partial sum of a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is defined to be
$$S_N=\sum_{n=0}^Na_n=a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_N.$$
([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Definition)). Thus the first few partial sums of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{2n+1}$$
are
$$\begin{align*}
S_0 & =\left[(-1)^0\frac{1}{2\cdot 0+1}\right]=1\\\\\\
S_1 &  =\left[(-1)^0\frac{1}{2\cdot 0+1}\right]+\left[(-1)^1\frac{1}{2\cdot 1+1}\right]=1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}\\\\\\
S_2 &  =\left[(-1)^0\frac{1}{2\cdot 0+1}\right]+\left[(-1)^1\frac{1}{2\cdot 1+1}\right]+\left[(-1)^2\frac{1}{2\cdot 2+1}\right]=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}=\frac{13}{15}\\
\end{align*}$$
I leave it to you calculate them up to $S_{10}$ (you will probably want to use Wolfram Alpha or a calculator.)

Answer (score 2):

Answering 4 year later! I wanted to see if there was a <s>closed</s> nice form for the partial sums and this post is about as good as anywhere to place my findings.

$$S_k=\sum_{n=0}^k{\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}}$$

$S_0=1,\\ S_1=\frac{2}{3},\\ S_2=\frac{13}{15},\\ S_3= \frac{76}{105},\\S_4=\frac{789}{945},\\
S_5=\frac{7734}{10395},\\
S_6=\frac{110937}{135135} ,\\
S_7=\frac{1528920}{2027025},\\
S_8=\frac{28018665}{34459425},\\
S_{9}=\frac{497895210}{654729075}$

And in general,

$S_n =\frac{a_n}{b_n}$

Where $a_n$ is [A024199](https://oeis.org/A024199)$(n)$ and $b_n=(2n+1)!!$ is [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147)$(n)$ and double factorial is defined in the [classic way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) Based on how A024199 is defined, it doesn't look like there is a nice way to express the fraction $S_n$ without invoking $\Sigma$ notation.

Comment: Downvote? I will delete if I get a second downvote. I can't quite see how this post hurts this site... Care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

*To calculate the sum of the series:*

We know that the power series of $\frac1{1+x}$ is
$$\frac1{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n $$
so we integrate term by term for $|x|<1$
$$\arctan x=\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}x^{2n+1} $$

the series is convergent for $x=1$ then we find

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\arctan 1=\frac\pi4$$

Comment: That was not the question asked.