# Evaluating a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Further to my integral question earlier, how can I evaluate the series:

$\sum^{2n+1}_{k=0} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and then the limit as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695320/partial-sums-and-the-leibniz-formula-for-pi

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:
$\arctan(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} x^{2k+1}$. Let $x=1$.

Your sum approaches $\arctan(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.